# querySelectAll Not Selecting Proper Elements

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown menu with a really long ID, but part of it is _Country. I have a text box with a really long ID, but part of it is _State.

I'm trying to take the value from the dropdown Country and put it into the textbox State anytime someone selects an option in the Country dropdown.

Here is the JavaScript I have now. It worked fine before I tried using the wildcard, but now it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelectorAll('[id*="_Country"]').onchange = replicate;
function replicate() {
    var tb1 = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="_Country"]');
    var tb2 = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="_State"]');
    tb2.value = tb1.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) to get just *one* node.

Here's a sample ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/sLRPS/2/)):

```
<select id="test_Country">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="test_State">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<script>
    (function() {
        var country = document.querySelector('[id*="_Country"]');
        var state = document.querySelector('[id*="_State"]');
        country.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
            state.value = country.value;
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I think you mean `querySelector` in the second one

Comment: It's not worth adding another answer, but an alternative is to select the zeroeth element of the nodeList, using: `querySelectorAll('[id*="_Country"]')[0]` (though it *is* ugly).

Comment: @DavidThomas And (I'd think) more expensive.

Comment: Indeed, I tend to include that under 'ugly,' but yes; it has more than one flaw. But it remains an option.